# DDEV - Configure multiple environments

Tags: ddev

Is there a way to have multiple DDEV configurations for the same project? For example, we need to cover the case when we have several servers:

- production with Apache + PHP 7.3 + Composer 1;
- staging server with Apache + PHP 7.3, but a different. set of domains;
- development with Nginx + PHP. 7.4 + Elasticsearch + Redis + Composer 2, where we're working on the system upgrade.

Dev team needs to emulate at least development and "stating" environments. Some features/hotfixes for production are under development and should be released before the big upgrade. This is a typical situation for (for example) Magento 2 projects with heavy customizations.

Is there a way to have multiple different environments like `.ddev-prod`, `.ddev-dev` etc., and somehow pass env name to ddev or configure it?

What comes to my mind is that we can create multiple configurations and add some information to Readme.md like:

> "To start dev env: copy `.ddev-dev` to `.ddev` and run `ddev start`".

From your experience, what is the best way to maintain multiple environments?

Regards,
Max

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'd try would just be three different DDEV projects with different configuration (but the same code and database). That way you could easily see any differences. That would certainly solve the problem with mimicking the development server.

But it actually sounds like you need 3 branches of your code. Each branch could have different DDEV configuration and there you'd go. Use different project name for each.

Another approach would be to have a `config.prod.yaml`, `config.staging.yaml` and `config.dev.yaml` and copy just the one you want into the .ddev directory when you need it. But I think you'll be much happier with 3 branches of your code and 3 different project names.

Comment: `But I think you'll be much happier with 3 branches...`
Managing infra via `master` or a separate `infra` branch looks better to me. Having different DDEV configs in different branches means that:  
- in case of creating new feature branches from dev: not possible to merge `dev` into `staging` and `staging` into `prod`;  
- in case features are made from `master`: changes are lost when `dev` is re-assembled. |  `three different DDEV projects.` - Not sure what `DDEV projects` mean in this context. Do you mean different `.ddev` folders? Or having several infrastructure repositories?

Comment: A ddev project is a directory of code that has a .ddev folder and a unique name.